# Jetty HttpClient connect using SSL through proxy

Tags: ssl, https, proxy, jetty

I have a setup of Jetty's HttpClient connected using SSL to apache http server which routes the requests as HTTP to a web server:

HttpClient <--HTTPS--> http server <--HTTP--> web server.

This setup has been working for some time.
I'm now trying to add a proxy:
HttpClient <--HTTPS using CONNECT method--> proxy <--HTTPS--> http server <--HTTP--> web server

I'm using the following code to setup the proxy:

> httpClient.setProxy(new Address("proxyHost", proxyPort));

The proxy doesn't require authentication.

The SSL handshake seems to start OK, and looking at the TCP dump, I can see I'm getting the 'server hello' response.
However, the handshake later fails with the following error showing in the http server logs:

> [Wed Jun 26 12:49:42 2013] [debug] ssl_engine_io.c(1925): OpenSSL: I/O error, 5 bytes expected to read on BIO#7faefe130d00 [mem: 7faefe11f203]

Since the handshake fails, no HTTP requests are forwarded to the web server.

Using the same setup, but replacing Jetty HttpClient with url.openConnection() and HttpsURLConnection configuration as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1512268/378060 is working fine.

Connecting from the browser after configuring proxy and certificate also works.

Version details:
Jetty HttpClient: tried 7.4.2, 7.6.11, 8.1.11 (Windows)
Proxy is squid 2.7 (Windows)
apache http server 2.2.15(linux)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the same as the one described here: http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg01854.html.
Squid 2.7 isn't Http 1.1 compliant, but Http 1.0, so it was not responding with a keep-alive header to Jetty's Proxy-Connection:keep-alive header. Jetty was then forced to close the connection according to Http 1.0 rules.