# HttpsURLConnection ignores setSSLSocketFactory

Tags: https, proxy

I'm trying to access https webpages using proxy according to [How do a send an HTTPS request through a proxy in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511674/how-do-a-send-an-https-request-through-a-proxy-in-java)

But I ran into a strange problem: the HttpsURLConnection is ignoring the setSSLSocketFactory method. 
Here are my codes:

```
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL("https://www.google.com").openConnection();
connection.setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLTunnelSocketFactory("127.0.0.1", 8089));
```

This is the SSLTunnelSocketFactory class:

```
class SSLTunnelSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    public SSLTunnelSocketFactory(String proxyIpAddress, int proxyPort) {
        System.out.println("calling SSLTunnelSocketFactory");
    }
    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        System.out.println("calling createSocket");
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String s, int i) throws IOException,
            UnknownHostException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String s, int i, InetAddress inetAddress,
                               int i2) throws IOException,
            UnknownHostException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inetAddress,
                               int i) throws IOException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress inetAddress, int i,
                               InetAddress inetAddress2,
                               int i2) throws IOException {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here is the output:

```
calling SSLTunnelSocketFactory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

You can see that "calling createSocket" was not printed, and a timeout exception occured.
This means that the setSSLSocketFactory method is ignored, which should not happen.

Could you please help me deal with this problem?

Comment: is the issue fixed ? If so please let us know solution

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to set
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);

Refer to this solution-https://community.oracle.com/thread/1536034?start=0&tstart=0