# How to access https through http proxy in Java?

Tags: java, proxy

I have a http proxy ip 218.106.96.211 and it's possible to access a website through the proxy.

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(new HttpHost("218.106.96.211", 80, "http")).build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/");
request.setConfig(config);
```

and it's possible to access a https website in java.

```
SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(new File("file.storage"), null, new TrustSelfSignedStrategy()).build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null,SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.def.com");
```

but if I access the https through the proxy, server responsed `HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request`, so what's the right way to access https through http proxy in java?

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511674/how-do-a-send-an-https-request-through-a-proxy-in-java

Comment: @Baderous thanks, I did not find this in my search

Comment: Or try http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e485 - Custom HttpRoutePlanner